# Missing semicolon(;) at end of SQL statement

Tags: vb.net, ms-access-2010, vb.net-2010

I don't know where I should put the semicolon. Here's my code:

```
Try
    cn.Open()

    Dim query As String = "INSERT INTO CheckoutTable(PatientID,_Name,_Age,_Gender,_Phone,_Address,_Disease,_DateIN,_DateOUT,_Building,_RoomNo,_RoomType,_UnitPrice,_Status,_MASP,_Price) VALUES('" & txtPID.Text & "','" & txtName.Text & "','" & txtAge.Text & "','" & cmbGender.Text & "','" & txtPhone.Text & "','" & txtAddress.Text & "','" & txtDisease.Text & "',' " & txtDI.Text & " ',' " & txtDO.Text & " ','" & txtRT.Text & "','" & txtBuilding.Text & "','" & txtRN.Text & "',' " & txtMNS.Text & " ',' " & txtUnitPrice.Text & " ',' " & cmbStatus.Text & " ','" & txtPrice.Text & "')" & _
        "DELETE From RegistrationTable where [_Name]='" & ListBox1.Text & "'" & _
        "Select * from RegistrationTable"

    Dim cmds As New OleDbCommand
    With cmds
        .CommandText = query
        .Connection = cn
        .ExecuteNonQuery()
    End With
    MsgBox("Checkout Success", MsgBoxStyle.Information)

    cn.Close()
Catch ex As Exception
    MsgBox(ex.Message)
End Try
```

Comment: Have you tried putting spaces on the end of each line of SQL? E.g. you have no space between ListBox1.Text & "'" and "Select".

Comment: definitly not a good idea to execute a select with a "nonquery" .... ok, to your question: immidiatly BEFORE the delete ntatement you will need a ; and the same is true for your insert, but you will not get data with a .ExecuteNonQuery()

Comment: @ChrisPeacock sir i already solve my problem :) thank you!

Comment: @ThomasKrojer i change my code already sir . into (insert query , Delete query and my code for display item in my listbox )

Comment: Consider using parameterized queries so you arent at risk for SQL injection attacks.

Comment: @StingyJack maybe , but it depends on how you use your code .

Comment: @princenhielcada -  in your above code, you are accepting user input without sanitizing it, so you are indeed vulnerable.

Comment: @princenhielcada Parameterized queries are the simplest way to protect against SQL injection attacks while also not discriminating against the Irish (O'Donnels and other apostrophe names).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Try
    cn.Open()

    Dim insertQuery as String = "INSERT INTO CheckoutTable(PatientID,_Name,_Age,_Gender,_Phone,_Address,_Disease,_DateIN,_DateOUT,_Building,_RoomNo,_RoomType,_UnitPrice,_Status,_MASP,_Price) " & _
                                "VALUES(@PatientID, @Name, @Age, @Gender, @Phone, @Address, @Disease , @DateIn, @DateOut, @Building, @RoomNo, @RoomType, @UnitPrice, @Status, @MASP, @Price) "
    Dim deleteQuery as String = "DELETE From RegistrationTable where [_Name]= @RegName " 
    Dim selectQuery as String = "Select * from RegistrationTable"

    Dim insertCmd As New OleDbCommand
    Dim deleteCmd as New OleDbCommand

    With insertCmd
        .Connection = cn
        .CommandText = insertQuery
        .Parameters.AddWithValue("@PatientID", txtPID.Text)
        .Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", txtName.Text)
        .Parameters.AddWithValue("@Age", txtAge.Text)
        .Parameters.AddWithValue("@Gender", cmbGender.Text)
        .Parameters.AddWithValue("@Phone", txtPhone.Text)
        .Parameters.AddWithValue("@Address", txtAddress.Text)
        .Parameters.AddWithValue("@Disease", txtDisease.Text)
        .Parameters.AddWithValue("@DateIn", txtDI.Text)
        .Parameters.AddWithValue("@DateOUT", txtDO.Text)
        .Parameters.AddWithValue("@Building", txtBuilding.Text)
        .Parameters.AddWithValue("@RoomNo", txtRN.Text)
        .Parameters.AddWithValue("@RoomType", txtRT.Text)
        .Parameters.AddWithValue("@UnitPrice", txtUnitPrice.Text)
        .Parameters.AddWithValue("@MASP", txtMNS.Text)
        .Parameters.AddWithValue("@Status", cmbStatus.Text)
        .Parameters.AddWithValue("@Price", txtPrice.Text)
        .ExecuteNonQuery()
    End With

    With deleteCmd
        .Connection = cn
        .CommandText = deleteQuery
        .Parameters.AddWithValue("@RegName", ListBox1.Text)
        .ExecuteNonQuery()
    End With
    MsgBox("Checkout Success", MsgBoxStyle.Information)

    cn.Close()
Catch ex As Exception
    MsgBox(ex.Message)
End Try
```

@StingyJack is right, I could break your db 6 ways from sunday if I had access to your interface as you're currently not doing ANYTHING to mitigate SQL injection.  In addition to parameterizing your queries to protect against injection, I removed the need to HAVE a ; at the end of each DML statement in your query, by breaking them into separate commands.  The select and displaying it's results, I leave to you.

Comment: It might double the number of lines of code, but it is much easier to read than the "1-liner" from the OP. Though, I don't think the `& ListBox1.Text` in the initialization of `deleteQuery` is wanted.

Comment: Nope, thanks for the catch AWinkle.  And yeah, sometimes to do things right you need to be more verbose.  But I guarantee little bobby tables would have a field day with the original code.